# Precaution to be taken when loading an external page in my web app

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I would like to allow the user to add a web-address to its comments and to allow a reader to load the content of this page, inside a div, in my web application.
Which step do I have to take to make sure the loaded page does not run any nasty code?

Comment: Load it in an `<iframe>` and let the browser handle security.

Comment: avoid using <iframe>, you can easily load a page into html element (eg. a div) using jQuery. iframe has security loopholes...